# xcode prefix header build error for opencv

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv

I'm trying to add opencv framework to my project, and I'm unable to build successfully.

Here is my .pch

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <FMDB/FMDB.h>
#import <SAMKeychain/SAMKeychain.h>
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
#endif

// cocoa lumberjack logging
#define LOG_LEVEL_DEF ddLogLevel
#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>
#import <BadgeLabel/BadgeLabel.h>

static const DDLogLevel ddLogLevel = DDLogLevelVerbose;
```

and I get the error:

```
Expected identifier or (...
```

in file included from /..../..../.pch : 14

This error only happens when I changed one class extension from .m to .mm. I need to change that class extension as I'm using opencv methods in that class.

If I dont use the opencv code in my ImageManager class, and change back the extension from .mm to .m, then it builds successfully.

ImageManager.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <opencv2/videoio/cap_ios.h>

@interface ImageManager : NSObject

@end
```

Here is the ImageManager.mm

```
#import "ImageManager.h"
@implementation ImageManager

@end
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the c++ includes after these for Obj-C and see what happens?

Comment: yes i did, i moved the #ifdef __cplusplus part below the declaration of objc part, but it gave me error to move it on top of apple declaration headers. Hence I put it on top. @A.A

Comment: And what's the complete error message and the line it happens?